# Setting the width of a select input based on ngOptions with angular

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to set the `width` of the dropdowns based on the max option length.  I am using angular to populate the selects with `ng-options`.  Is there an angular approach to doing this or should I just use CSS and javascript?  My first attempt was to make a directive and access the `ngOptions`.

Here's the directive code

```
app.directive('sizeToOptions', function () {
return { 
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: false,
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        //Need to get ngOptions here and keep the greatest option width
        //var maxWidth = //maxwidth
        elem.css('width', maxWidth);
        scope.$apply(function () {
            scope.width = maxWidth;
        });
    }
}; 
});
```

Comment: If you're wanting to modify the DOM, a directive would be the way to do it. Post your code & a JSFiddle.

Comment: @EnigmaRM  I posted the directive

Comment: var widths = elem.find('option').width(); Then traverse the widths array and find max. And you probably do not need scope.$apply.

Comment: @aet `elem.find('option').width();` is null

Comment: var options = elem.find('option'); var maxWidth = 0; for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) { var w = options[i].width(); if (w > maxWidth) { maxWidth = w; } }

Comment: @aet `var options = elem.find('option'); var maxWidth = 0; for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) { var w = options[i].width(); if (w > maxWidth) { maxWidth = w; } }` maxWidth is 0.  Maybe the options aren't created yet?  This is the html `<select data-ng-model="newItem.Minutes" data-ng-options="d for d in Minutes" data-ng-selected="newItem.Minutes" size-to-content></select>`